# Read a file's content from ServiceStack web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, servicestack, razorengine

i am trying to read a Razor formatted (.cshtml) file's content to be parse into Razor.Parse method to send an Html Email out. However I have problem reading the file from the webservice.
How can i get the string content from the .cshtml file?

```
public class SendConfirmationEmailService : Service
{
    public ConfirmationEmailResponse Post(ConfirmationEmailRequest request)
    {
          var emailModel = new EmailModel{ };
          var templateString = ???????
          var body = Razor.Parse(templateString, emailModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/") + "FileNameWithPath");
```